# Minitest and Fixtures: Passing in the correct params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

So I am trying to create a simple integration test in Rails. I want to test my login form. I just can't really figure out how to pass my params correctly. My .yml file is called agents.yml. My fixture file is:

```
one: 
  first_name: firstNameTest
  last_name: lastNameTest
  email: test@test.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(Agent, '123456') %>
```

that should be ok.

Two tests I tried which both give me an error. The first one, following the Ruby.docs:

```
    class FlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    test "Login and navigate" do 
        get "/agents/sign_in"
        post "/agents/sign_in", email: agents(:one).email, password: 
        agents(:one).password
        follow_redirect!
      end 

    end
```

the second version:

```
class FlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    test "Login and navigate" do 
    get "/agents/sign_in"
    post "/agents/sign_in", agent: {email: agents(:one).email, password: '123456'}
    follow_redirect!
  end 

end
```

Both throw me an error:

```
Error:
FlowsTest#test_Login_and_navigate:
ArgumentError: unknown keywords: email, password
    test/integration/Flows_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:FlowsTest>'
```

I guess I'm passing in the params in a wrong way. Because email and password should be taken from the fixtures, or am I wrong? Can anyone help? Would be very much appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :agents


      def test_login
        get "/agents/sign_in"
        assert_equal 200, status  
        post "/agents/sign_in", params: { email: agents(:one).email,
          password: agents(:one).password }
        follow_redirect!
        assert_equal 200, status
        assert_equal "/", path
      end 
    end
```